# Android Studio Project Structure - library dependency options only offer alpha versions

Tags: android, android-studio, project-structure

What controls the versions offered in the "Choose Library Dependency" list? I only see alpha versions.

File > Project Structure...

[image: Where Project Structure is located]

Select app under Modules > Dependencies tab > green plus sign on the right > Library Dependency
[image: Project Structure > Dependencies > Add Library Dependency]

What my gradle file looks like. I had to select the -alpha1 version then modify the gradle file to pull in the correct version.

[image: gradle file]

The version of android studio version I'm running.
[image: android studio version]

Comment: More detail would help people answer your question. What versions do you think are available other than the ones shown? What makes you think they're available? What specific versions are shown (e.g. a screenshot)? How did you get to the Choose Library Dependency list you're referring to?

Comment: Also, the question title should summarize the question.

Comment: @LarsH, I've updated my question to include screenshots and a bit more information. The versions that I'm looking for are 25.3.1 for multiple different libraries because I'm targeting SDK 25. What makes me think that they are available is https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-3-1. The specific versions are mostly v7:26.0.0-alpha1. I got to the Choose Library Dependency list by File > Project Structure > selecting app under Modules > Dependencies tab > green plus sign on right > Add Library Dependency. I also updated the title to summarize the question.

Comment: Excellent, +1. I'm sorry I don't know the answer, but I hope someone else can help.